# Make universal binary for IOS4 (iPhone 4) and 3G

Tags: iphone, ios4

How to make universal binary of one app, which can correctly run on 3G and support multitasking on iPhone 4?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The term "universal binary" here is a misnomer, since that is only for iPad/iPhone combined apps. If all you want to do is compile a build that works on both iPhone 4 and iPhone 3G, you need to download and install SDK 4, set 4.0 as the "Base SDK", and then set your "Deployment Target" to whatever minimum version of iOS you want to allow to run your app. Some people use a setting of 3.1.3, some people keep that setting at 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) under [Starting Your Project](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW1).

Comment: Thanks, if I have only iPhone 3G, may I use it and iPhone 4 simulator to test this app on both 3G and iOS 4 (with all features of iOS4 like multitasking, Retina display and so on)? Or I need iPhone 4 device anyway for testing this universal app?

Comment: So I dont want to split my app into 2 separate apps. I want to write into AppsStore that the App supports OS 3.0 and so on and works correctly on iPhone 4 supporting multitasking.

Comment: You will need a device to test multitasking.  The simulator is sufficient for retina display.

Comment: You can test both multitasking and the high-resolution display with the simulator in iPhone and iPhone 4 modes.